# Troubleshooting: does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, windows, class

I am trying to create a multi class program that creates student objects then allows you to change the value for the undeclared major for one of the student objects.

Here is my code:

`StudentApp.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PA04CoddR
{
    class StudentApp
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            DisplayTitle();
            Student firstStudent = new Student("Robert", "Codd");
            DisplayInfo(firstStudent);
            Student secondStudent = new Student("Alexander", "Clemens", "FIN");
            DisplayInfo(secondStudent);
            GetMajor(firstStudent);
            DisplayInfo(firstStudent);
            TerminateProgram();

        }

        public void DisplayTitle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Programming Assignment 4 - Creating a Class - Robert S. Codd");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________");

        }

        public void DisplayInfo(Student newStudent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Frist Name: " + newStudent.GetFirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + newStudent.GetLastName);
            Console.WriteLine("Major: " + newStudent.GetMajor);

        }

        public void GetMajor(Student newStudent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tHello {0} {1}", newStudent.GetFirstName, newStudent.GetLastName);
            Console.WriteLine("\tPlease enter your major: ");
            string majorIn = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            newStudent.SetMajor(majorIn);

        }

        public void TerminateProgram()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("___________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("PRESS ANY KEY TO TERMINATE...");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

`Student.CS`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PA04CoddR
{
    class Student
    {
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string major;

        public Student()
        {
        }

        public Student(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            firstName = GetFirstName;
            lastName = GetLastName;
            major = "Undeclared";
        }

        public Student(string firstName, string lastName, string major)
        {
            firstName = GetFirstName;
            lastName = GetLastName;
            major = GetMajor;
        }

        public string GetFirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
            }
        }

        public string GetLastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
            }
        }

        public string GetMajor
        {
            get
            {
                return major;
            }
            set
            {
                major = value;
            }
        }

        public string SetMajor(string majorIn)
        {
            major = majorIn;
            return majorIn;
        } 
    }
}
```

I have no errors being listed or given in the IDE but as soon as I try to compile the program it returns the error: "Does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point"

I did some research on here and other online resources and found a few things that seemed promising for solving my problem like changing the main method to static but as soon as I tried that every thing in my main method is returning a syntax error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, I am a learning programmer so I'm sure it is something fairly simple and I just do not full understand the concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main routine needs to be static:

```
 public static void Main()
 {
```

However, doing that will require you to create an instance of `StudentApp`:

```
 public static void Main()
 {
     var app = new StudentApp();
     app.DisplayTitle(); // Call method on the instance

     // Do the same for your other methods...
```

This is because your other methods that your `Main()` methods use are instance methods, not static methods.

Comment: `StudentApp` is itself, so `this` would suffice, would it not?

Comment: @KarlAnderson No - there is no `this` inside of a *static* method.

Comment: duh, I just realized that after I typed it. LOL

Comment: I did all this and was able to get the program to run and am able to access and edit the undeclared major and then redisplay the updated student object. Now my problem is that the output is not displaying the names properly, really at all. I am trying the step in feature of visual studios to try and figure out why this is but thank you for your input! It's really appreciated.

Comment: @user2864614 Your Student constructor is backwards - Should be `GetFirstName = firstName;`  Note that I'd also recommend just naming your properties "FirstName", not "GetFirstName", etc

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
public void Main()
```

But you need to have this:

```
public static void Main()
```

Comment: This alone won't cut it - this will cause lots of other errors to 
surface

Answer (score 1):

Your `Main` method must be static, change the other methods in `StudentApp` to static too as they do not make use of any instance state.

Answer (score 1):

You must add static to public void Main like this:

```
public static void main(string[]args)
{
   //Your code
}
```

If want use the other class you must add static to Student class and its all methods and to Student like StudentApp.
This because a static method can call only other static methods.

Comment: This alone won't cut it - this will cause lots of other errors to 
surface, as the other methods aren't static

Comment: @ReedCopsey i know infact i have edited the main post. Thanks